# How to send push notifications to non android/ios device connected to internet with no public ip address? (e.g. raspberry pi with umts card)

Tags: android, linux, azure, push-notification, raspberry-pi

1.[os=linux]
 Having a non android/ios device there is no standard push service available.

2.[no-public-ip/incoming ports blocked]
 Connecting the Device to internet via UMTS stick and having no public ip and having all usable ports blocked by APN, no SSH connection will work..

3.
[low energy constraints]
Running on battery no polling shall be implemented.

Question: How to implement own push service (on virtual server/azure/aws) or how to to use android/ios push service on linux?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're asking how to send a push notification to your Pi, not how to send a push notification from your Pi to your Android device?